# Chamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

*This one should require a little less digging, I think.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- According to R' Akiva, cited in the haggada, there were **250** plagues (or "plague components") during קריאת ים סוף.
- Korach's "עדה" consisted of **250** men. (Bamidbar 16:2)

Answer (score 4):

There were 210+40=250 years from entering Egypt to entering Israel (or, to the tune, "two FIFty were the YEARS outside IS-RAEL").

Answer (score 3):

250 [*shekel*, I think] was the quantity of *k'ne vosem* in the *shemen hamishcha* (anointing oil). ([*Sh'mos* 30:23.](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%92))

Answer (score 3):

Instead of weighing out 500 shekel of kin'mon-besem and putting some extra on to tip the scale, the kinmon-besem was weighed in 2 shifts of 250 so that there will be 2 extra "scale tipping portions".

This is why the Torah writes the recipe as "half of it is 250", to teach us that

**a)** the kinmon-besem gets 2 of those extras

and by induction

**b)** the measurements are not exact, you add a little more to all the measurements

([Rashi Ki Sisa 30:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=506) and [Krisus 5a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=5&format=pdf))

(Nontraditional translations assume only 250, half of the mar-dror)

Answer (score 3):

דברי הימים ב: ח. י.
ואלה שרי הנציבים אשר למלך שלמה **חמשים ומאתים** הרדים בעם

יחזקאל: מח. יז.
והיה מגרש לעיר צפונה **חמשים ומאתים** ונגבה **חמשים ומאתים** וקדימה **חמשים ומאתים** וימה **חמשים ומאתים**

Answer (score 3):

A man has 248 Aivorim and a lady has 252 Aivorim. Together that equals 500. We light 2 candles for Shabbos. Ner = 250. 2 x 250 = 500

Comment: Is there a source for this connection?

Comment: [Ben Ish Chai, דרוש ד' לשבת כלה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21525&pgnum=124) (second column of the page).

Comment: _Taame Haminhagim_ 959 relates this same _gimatriya_ to the candles the escorts carry to the _chupa_.